# HTML form with multiple file upload fields, how to check max file size client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this simple script that checks max file size client side in a html form. The check works for the first file added, but I'm having a struggle finding out how to apply the method for checking the other input fields as they are dynamically added.

The check is based on `var uploadField = document.getElementById("file1");`

Check out this fiddle to better understand the issue:      http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/16341/

Any tips on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to delegate for objects that are dynamically added.
In your code, use this instead of addressing file1 specifically

```
$("#files").delegate("input","change",function(){
        if(this.files[0].size > 2000000){
                alert('File is larger than 2MB. Please choose a smaller file');
       this.value = "";
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Your solution is even more elegant because it doesn't clear already validated files if a larger than 2MB file is added after the first (validated) file.

Comment: NP! While I'm at it, is possible to implement a check on file types as well, eg. limit to only .jpg, .gif and so on?

Comment: There's 'accept' attribute for input type file, but be advised that client can workaround it, so you should perform this check on server as well

Answer (score 1):

Do a check for total number of `File Input` items and validate. Updated http://jsfiddle.net/zz8c9c9u/5/

Comment: Thanks James, that's brilliant!